# C# - Why can't I make an IEnumerable of a generic interface type?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ienumerable

As an example, I have an application that makes fruit smoothies. I can make an `IEnumerable` list of Apple smoothies and that works.

I want to be able to make a generic list of smoothies `IEnumerable<ISmoothie<IFruit>>` in case I decide to add another Fruit down the line like say an Orange. When I try to do that the code will not compile and I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IEnumerable<ISmoothie<Apple>> appleSmoothies = new List<ISmoothie<Apple>>();   // I Can specifically make Apple Smoothies!
        IEnumerable<ISmoothie<IFruit>> genericSmoothies = new List<Smoothie<Apple>>(); // Does Not Compile - What if I want generic Smoothies? 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    public class Apple : IApple
    {
        // Concrete Implimentation of an Apple
    }

    public interface IApple : IFruit
    {
        // Specific Interface for Apples
    }

    public interface IFruit
    {
        // Basic Fruit Interface for all Fruits
    }

    public class Smoothie<T> : ISmoothie<T> where T : IFruit
    {
        // Generic Fruit Smoothie
        public List<T> Ingredients {get; set;}
        public int Size {get; set;}
        public void Drink()
        {
            // Drink Logic
        }
    }

    public interface ISmoothie<T> where T : IFruit
    {
        List<T> Ingredients {get; set;}
        int Size {get; set;}
        void Drink();
    }
}
```

Comment: Michael Randall's answer is correct given the content of your `ISmoothie` interface, but should you actually start adding methods and properties that take `T` as a parameter then the answer won't work for you. Can you show us what your actual interface looks like?

Comment: You're absolutely right, just updated the code. New error is about invalid variance.

Comment: Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'Program.ISmoothie<T>.Ingredients'. 'T' is covariant.

Comment: Then we have a problem and you need to think about why you are doing this, what problem are you actually trying to solve? why not just `IEnumerable<ISmoothie<Apple>>  genericSmoothies = new List<Smoothie<Apple>>()`

Comment: In my real application this would cause a circular dependance because I have placed all my interfaces into the Blender.Interfaces.cs project but my logic is in Blender.Model.cs ... I probably need to sit down and think about this one.

Comment: @JohnAugust - Don't break your question by adding the `out` to the interface.

Comment: If `ISmoothie<T>` could be `ISmoothie<out T>` then you could cast a `ISmoothie<Apple>` to `ISmoothie<IFruit>`; which then means you could call `Ingredients` to get an `List<IFruit>` and thus be able to add a `Banana` to a list which would only accept an `Apple`. It just doesn't make sense trying to do this.

Comment: @JohnAugust - Can you show us how you get a circular dependency?

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do unless you restrict yourself to either `in` or `out`. That's for a good reason. If you have type `IEnumerable<ISmoothie<IFruit>>`, and you want to put apples, oranges etc inside it, then it is no longer one type, is it? That means you will be casting all the time which is the same as using an `ArrayList`, so then what's the point of using a `List<T>`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Totally makes sense after thinking about it. I'm trying to mix apples and oranges in the same bag which breaks type saftey. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `out` parameter to your interface to specify *Covariance*

```
public interface ISmoothie<out T> where T : IFruit
{
}
```

---

[out (generic modifier) (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

> For generic type parameters, the out keyword specifies that the type
>   parameter is covariant. You can use the out keyword in generic
>   interfaces and delegates.
>
> **Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than that specified
>   by the generic parameter**. This allows for implicit conversion of
>   classes that implement covariant interfaces and implicit conversion of
>   delegate types. Covariance and contravariance are supported for
>   reference types, but they are not supported for value types.

**Update**

There are limitation when using the out parameter,

```
public class Smoothie<T> : ISmoothie<T> where T : IFruit
{
   // Generic Fruit Smoothie
   public T Type { get; set; } // we can do this
}

public interface ISmoothie<out T> where T : IFruit
{
   T Type { get; set; } // compiler error CS1961 Invalid variance: 
}
```

`out T` means that type `T` is restricted to appear only as a returned (outbound) value in methods of the generic class, interface or method

Comment: It would be worth noting that this only works because the OP hasn't shown us any members of `ISmoothie<out T>` that take `T` as a parameter.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah i saw your comment, and its a worthy one

Comment: Thanks Randall! I added in more details regarding the interface members of ISmoothie. I do indeed have members that take T as a param. Is there any other solutions to this?

Comment: @JohnAugust - You now need to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelRandall - Sorry to put a fly in the ointment.

Comment: @Enigmativity that wasn't a fly, it was a hippo!

Comment: @MichaelRandall - You had a lot of excellent looking ointment - it needed something bigger than a fly to bring down such a nice answer. That's why I'm sorry about it.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Giving you the answer since it was helpful in having me understand the problem. I need to re-think how I'm laying out the project to really solve the problem. Also, I had no idea you could use 'out' on with generics like that. I always used them for 'out' method paramaters in the past so thanks!